# fontspec-color not working correctly with microtype package

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, luaotfload

If I use the fontspec package together with the microtype package, the color-feature of fontspec does only colarize the last line of the paragraph instead of the whole paragraph, as the grouped `\addfontfeature`-command should work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn%
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test.

\begingroup%
    \addfontfeature{Color=blue}%
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
    Test. Test.
\endgroup%

Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test.
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Badly colored paragraph].

I use LuaLaTeX with `fontspec.sty` (2013/03/16 v2.3a) and `microtype.sty` (2013/03/13 v2.5).

Comment: It may be caused by LuaLaTeX. With XeLaTeX it works fine.

Comment: looks like a problem with package `microtype`. File a bug report to the author

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `fontspec` (2012/05/06 v2.2b) and `microtype` (2010/01/10 v2.4) on `lualatex` (beta-0.70.2-2012052410). But I think, this should be posted in the correct bugtrackers or mailing lists.

Comment: Same problem here. Using `microtype` v2.5 as well. It seems to be related to font expansion. Setting `expansion=false` makes it disapper. You might want to include that in case you file a bug report. But `fontspec` might be involved in the problem as well, as it also disappears when we leave expansion on, but use plain old `\color` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in `luaotfload`, not in `microtype` nor `fontspec`. (@AndrewStacey had already reported this a while ago to me.) The same happens with plain luatex:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\x="DejaVu Serif":color=FF00FF;expansion=default; \x
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\hsize=7cm
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
\bye
```

Only those lines appear in colour where no expansion takes place (here, the last line). It seems that the colourizing routine from `luaotfload` (in file `otfl-font-clr.lua`) doesn't recognize the expanded fonts as instances of the same base font.

**EDIT:** This bug has been fixed in `luaotfload` v2.2, thanks to Élie Roux and Philipp Gesang.